# How to get back the onclick effect on a button in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, user-interface, button, javafx

I looked for a solution on this particular issue & found a few ones on Silverlight & JavaScript, but not on JavaFX.

Now on the issue:

I am designing a GUI in JavaFX where I have added two buttons: ADD & REMOVE

I have styled the ADD button using CSS, but it has lost its hovering & onclick effect. I have attached a couple of images for better understanding of the issue

1. If you look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYB06.png) photo here, you'll see that when the REMOVE button is clicked, **it slightly changes its color to give the effect that it is being clicked currently**. Also when the cursor hovers over it, **it turns slightly brighter than it usually is**.

The code for this button is given below

```
VBox rightBox = new VBox(remBttn);
rightBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
rightBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
remBttn.setPadding(new Insets(100,0,100,0));
remBttn.setPrefWidth(100);
remBttn.setOnAction(
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                myLabel.setText("You Clicked The REMOVE Button");
            }
        });
remBttn.setFont(Font.font(20));
```

2. However, if you look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Ye3.png) photo here, you'll notice that **hovering and clicking have no effects** on it. I don't know much about CSS, so I copied a snippet of code from a random Website to style my button. But I think that is where I messed it all up.

The code for that give below:

```
VBox leftBox = new VBox(addBttn);
leftBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));
leftBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
addBttn.setPadding(new Insets(100,0,100,0));
addBttn.setPrefWidth(100);
addBttn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #c3c4c4, linear-gradient(#d6d6d6 50%, white 100%), radial-gradient(center 50% -40%, radius 200%, #e6e6e6 45%, rgba(230,230,230,0) 50%); -fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-insets: 0,1,1; -fx-text-fill: black; -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 3, 0.0 , 0 , 1 ); -fx-focus-color: transparent; -fx-base: coral;");
```

So I want to know what methods or properties can be used to bring back the same effects without changing the style.

Comment: In your posted code I do not see any style definition for the remove button.

Comment: Yes! I haven't because I didn't need to. JavaFX default buttons, I'm guessing, already have such things defined. I styled the ADD button, for which I'm no longer getting the default hover over and on click effects. So I was wondering if there were certain methods or properties that could redefine such effects for the ADD button

Answer (score 3):

The moment you change the background of the button,It will lose its default hover and click effect,So I think the better way of doing it is to set the hover and click effect in css.

By the way instead of setting style again in code, just create a css file in your **src** folder then link it to your scene using this.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("your_file_name.css").toExternalForm());
```

Then add an id to your add button using `addBttn.setId("addBttn");` Then
refer to it in **your_file_name.css** like

```
#addBttn{
   /*Your custom default button style*/
}

#addBttn:hover{
   /*Your button style on hover*/
}

#addBttn:pressed{
    /*Your button style on pressed*/
 }
```

Hope this solves your problem.